# What is known about the image of the Jones polynomial functor (in particular on the class of all knots)?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, laurent-series, knot-theory, knot-invariants

**Question.**

What exactly is known about the *image of the Jones-polynomial-function* $V$: $\{$ all links $\}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{Z}[t^{-1/2},t^{1/2}]$?

Are there references explicitly and transparently adressing this question, to the point of *desribing the fibers of given Laurent polynomials*?

"How" well understood is $\mathrm{im}(V)$?

What are citable references in the literature on this?

**Remarks.**

(0) Of course, the literature contains a wealth of precise results relevant on this, yet I never saw a reference, let alone a survey addressing this question upfront.

(1) A basic remark to make is that it is known that $0\notin\mathrm{im}(V)$.

(2) I take it that $\mathrm{im}$ can be considered not completely understood, at least in the sense that, notoriously, it is not known whether $V^{-1}(1)$ contains a non-trivial knot.

(3) I in particular need to know as much as conveniently possible about the image of $V$ restricted to the class of all *knots*$=$(1-component links).